# jquery claaclled when user clickss level function passing value

Tags: jquery, function, parameter-passing

In my online shop page I have several items that users can click to add to their cart.

```
<a class="btn add2Cart" href="#">Add item 123to Cart</a>
<a class="btn add2Cart" href="#">Add item 456 to Cart</a>
```

Is it possible to create a single jquery function called each time an item is clicked, passing the item code as value?

```
$('.add2Cart').click(function() { *** How do I get the item value here? ***}
```

Comment: there are too many missing details to help much.

the item value will be relative to the item itself.  perhaps something like `$(this).next('input')` ?  or maybe you could have a data object tied to the `a` that has that information : `$(this).data('value')` ? 

P.S. you don't need to use `a` tags to make something clickable by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is!

Are you able to change the HTML? If you could make it:

```
<a class="btn add2Cart" data-product-number="123" href="#">Add item 123to Cart</a>
<a class="btn add2Cart" data-product-number="456" href="#">Add item 456 to Cart</a>
```

Then you'd be able to use:

```
$('.add2Cart').click(function() {
  var productNumber = $(this).attr('data-product-number');

  // add to the cart using productNumber

}
```

If you normally add products to the cart by clicking a link, you might be able to make an ajax call that adds your product to the cart, making is *something* like this:

```
$('.add2Cart').click(function() {
  var productNumber = $(this).attr('data-product-number');

  // add to the cart using productNumber
  $.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/cart',
    data: {
      'product_id' : productNumber
    },
    success: function(){
      console.log('Product number '+productNumber+' was added to the cart.');
    }
  });

}
```